# Issue with DatePicker Change

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, uidatepicker

I'm working with Asp .net MVC3.I've the following table on view page,

```
      <table>
      <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>date1</th>
      <th>date2</th>
       </tr>
      @foreach(var item in Model.data)
      {
      <tr>
      <td>@item.Id</td>
      <td>@item.Name</td>
      @if(@item.date1==""){
         <td><input type="text" name="date1" class="date1"></td>
         }
      else{
<td>@Html.TextBox("date1",item.date1, new { @class="date1" })</td>
      }
       @if(@item.date2==""){
       <td><input type="text" name="date2" class="date2"></td>
         }
          else{
<td>@Html.TextBox("date2",item.date2, new { @class="date2" })</td>
         }
                </tr>
       }
      </table>
```

Following is the datepicker jquery which i'm using,

```
 $(function () {
    $(".date1").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/M/yy'
    });
    $(".date2").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/M/yy'
    });
});
```

first time when i select the date of 1st row,the selected date is updated in correct text box.But when i change the existing datevalue of a second row the date change happens in first row textbox.

Comment: Have you got some other javascript code that is manipulating these values?

Comment: please add demo in jsfiddle also

Comment: Please find the updated code

Comment: working fine http://jsfiddle.net/4PzGW/

Comment: but when it populates dynamically its not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    <table>
          <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>date1</th>
          <th>date2</th>
           </tr>
          @foreach(var item in Model.data)
          {
          <tr>
          <td>@item.Id</td>
          <td>@item.Name</td>
          <td><input type="text" id="date1" name="date1" class="date1" value="@item.date1=="" ? "" : @item.date1"/></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="date2" name="date2" class="date2" value="@item.date2=="" ? "" : @item.date2"/></td>
          </tr>
           }
          </table>

$(function () {
    $("#date1").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/M/yy'
    });
    $("#date2").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd/M/yy'
    });
});
```